# printing bit representation of numbers in python

Tags: python

I want to print the bit representation of numbers onto console, so that I can see all operations that are being done on bits itself.

How can I possibly do it in python?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

This kind of thing?

```
>>> ord('a')
97
>>> hex(ord('a'))
'0x61'
>>> bin(ord('a'))
'0b1100001'
```

Comment: Being strict, this is the binary representation of a number, but not necessarily the underlying bits in memory.

Answer (score 38):

**From Python 2.6** - with the [string.format method](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting):

```
"{0:b}".format(0x1234)
```

in particular, you might like to use padding, so that multiple prints of different numbers still line up:

```
"{0:16b}".format(0x1234)
```

and to have left padding with leading 0s rather than spaces:

```
"{0:016b}".format(0x1234)
```

**From Python 3.6** - with [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings):

The same three examples, with f-strings, would be:

```
f"{0x1234:b}"
f"{0x1234:16b}"
f"{0x1234:016b}"
```

Answer (score 35):

**In Python 2.6+**:

```
print bin(123)
```

Results in:

```
0b1111011
```

**In python 2.x**

```
>>> binary = lambda n: n>0 and [n&1]+binary(n>>1) or []
>>> binary(123)
[1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```

<sup>Note, example taken from: "Mark Dufour"  at http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2003-December/240914.html</sup>

Comment: you can further add bin = lambda b:'0b'+''.join(map(str,binary(b))), so it mimics 2.6+ completely

Comment: what is I want the binary padded with 0's to accommodate for a fixed length binary number.

Comment: `bin(-7)` returns `-0b111` but your function returns `[]`.

Answer (score 4):

Slightly off-topic, but might be helpful. For better user-friendly printing I would use custom print function, define representation characters and group spacing for better readability. Here is an example function, it takes a list/array and the group width:

```
def bprint(A, grp):
    for x in A:
        brp = "{:08b}".format(x)
        L=[]
        for i,b in enumerate(brp):
            if b=="1":
                L.append("k")
            else: 
                L.append("-")
            if (i+1)%grp ==0 :
                L.append(" ")

        print "".join(L) 

#run
A = [0,1,2,127,128,255]
bprint (A,4)
```

Output:

```
---- ----
---- ---k
---- --k-
-kkk kkkk
k--- ----
kkkk kkkk
```

Answer (score 3):

[The `bin` function](http://docs.python.org/3.1/library/functions.html#bin)