# Alternative of showbits() in Python to show 16 bit binary representation

Tags: python

I want to know, is there any built_in function in some module to show 16 bit binary representation of any number?

Comment: But i want its 16 bit representation...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that by 'any number', you mean 'an integer that can be represented in 16 bits':

As mentioned by another poster, the `bin()` function does a basic base-10 to base-2 conversion.

I don't *think* there's a built-in function to specifically give a 16-bit representation, but if the number is positive, you can simply pad out the beginning if you want to make it 16-bit:

```
def padded_bin(x):
    return bin(x)[2:].zfill(16) # the [2:] strips off the '0b' that bin() returns
```

If the number is negative, the standard representation is two's-complement (invert the bits, and add 1).

```
def padded_bin_with_complement(x):
    if x < 0:
        return bin((2**16) - abs(x))[2:].zfill(16)
    else:
        return bin(x)[2:].zfill(16)
```

(These functions don't check that the numbers are in range, but I'm sure you can add that trivially. As mentioned, they strip off the '0b' that bin() returns, but you can always add that back in.)

**EDIT:** actually, having a look at one of the answers to [printing bit representation of numbers in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054116/printing-bit-representation-of-numbers-in-python), you can use:

```
"{0:16b}".format(x)
```

in Python 2.6 and later. However, this handles negative numbers in the same way that `bin()` does, i.e. by adding a negative sign rather than giving a two's-complement representation.

Answer (score 0):

**bin** will return a binary string

```
>>> bin(1)
'0b1'
>>> bin(8)
'0b1000'
```