# byte to bit manipulation in python

Tags: python, byte, bit-manipulation

I have a bmp file that I read in my Python program. Once I have read in the bytes, I want to do bit-wise operations on each byte I read in. My program is:

```
with open("ship.bmp", "rb") as f:
    byte = f.read(1)
    while byte != b"":
        # Do stuff with byte.
        byte = f.read(1)
    print(byte)
```

output:

```
b'\xfe'
```

I was wondering how I can do manipulation on that? I.e convert it to bits. Some general pointers would be good. I lack experience with Python, so any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Is this Python 2 or 3? Looks like 3 but it's best to be sure, they're different in this case.

Comment: unrelated but you can change your while to a for loop `for byte in iter(lambda:f.read(1),b"")`

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Maybe he wants readability.

Comment: @mbomb007, unless you are stevie wonder that is readable

Comment: possible duplicate of [printing bit representation of numbers in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054116/printing-bit-representation-of-numbers-in-python). If you want to manipulate single bits, use the according operators: ~ ^ | &

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It's definitely not as readable. Tons of languages have while loops. Not many have a function called `iter` or identical `lambda` syntax. Using a `while` is inherently easier to read and understand.

Comment: @mbomb007, in your opinion, I prefer to not repeat lines of  code for no reason. Also python is a particular language not tons of languages so when in Rome...

Comment: @PadraicCunningham More languages emphasize readability, hence why it's *more* readable to use a while loop, even if that is readable to *you personally*.

Comment: @mbomb007,again I reiterate in your opinion, it was directed at the OP so to be honest what you think is somewhat irrelevant.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham Not any more irrelevant than your initial statement :)

Comment: @mbomb007,quite a bit more actually as you are neither the OP or myself.

Comment: My comment was directed at both. It's not possible to use the @ format for the OP in the comments below the question.

Comment: @mbomb007 What Padraic Cunningham has suggested is indeed the idiomatic way to do that thing in Python.

Comment: Python 3, i need to transform each bytes into bits, and then manipulate the bits

Answer (score 2):

`bytes` objects yield integers from 0 through 255 inclusive when indexed. So, just perform the bit manipulation on the result of indexing.

```
3>> b'\xfe'[0]
254
3>> b'\xfe'[0] ^ 0x55
171
```

Comment: A promt. The results wouldn't make sense otherwise

Comment: @Dunes: I modified my Python 3.x prompt so that I can easily differentiate between 3.x in one terminal and 2.x in another. The normal prompt in both is ">>> "

Answer (score 2):

`file.read(1)` constructs a length 1 bytes objects, which is a bit overkill when you want the byte as an integer. To access each byte as an integer the following would be more succinct, and have the benefit of using a for loop.

```
with open("ship.bmp", "rb") as f:
    byte_data = f.read()

for byte in byte_data:
    # do stuff with byte. eg.
    result = byte & 0x2
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, if i wanted to access the bits of a byte, how could i do that?

Comment: `byte = 7;index = 7;bit = (byte << index >> 7) % 2;print bit`

Comment: Or, if you want the 0th bit to be the bit on the far right, use `byte << 7-index >> 7` instead.

Comment: I had to use `% 2` because Python doesn't include unsigned right shift, since it doesn't have unsigned numbers.